# Using Arduino to connect Android tablet to USB Accessory

Tags: usb, arduino, accessory

I have an Arduino-compatible board with USB Host Shield.  It is connected to an Acer A100 Android tablet running "Ice Cream Sandwich" (Android 4.0.3) with Kernel 2.6.39.4.  (The tablet has a USB micro connector and does not support USB HOST mode and therefore cannot connect directly to a USB accessory device.)

This picture shows what I have been able to do successfully (but with my tablet in place of the phone).
http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/File:SeeeduinoADK_Setup.jpg

I would like to find an example of using an Android tablet connected to a USB Accessory (such as a keyboard or flash drive) via Arduino.

Connecting the USB accessory to the Arduino's USB micro connector (using an external power supply) does not work.

Can anyone provide me with such an example?

Comment: Can anyone please help with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it should work, I haven't tried it yet though.

Arduino should act as the middle man and should relay signals both from your tablet and the accessory.

Answer (score 0):

What code are you use?
This is: **adk_release_20120606**?

And what board are you use **SeeeduinoADK**?

I use board Seeeduino ADK, but unfortunately I could not make it work in **USB accessory mode**. My board work in only ADB (**MicroBridge mode**). See my [work example](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino3.php)

My tablet is Ainol Aurora with Android version 4.0.4 (CyanogenMod 9)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am using the Seeeduino ADK Main Board.  The code I use comes from: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/index.php?title=Seeeduino_ADK_Main_Board

Comment: The actual code I use is SeeeduinoADKDemo-App.zip and MicroBridge-ModifiedForSeeeduinoADK.zip.

Comment: Yes.  It works like in this photo: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/File:SeeeduinoADK_Setup.jpg

Comment: Maybe you tablet not working in USB accessory mode, use MicroBridge. My tablet Ainol Aurora with Android version 4.0.4 (CyanogenMod 9) not working in USB accessory mode too.